# How to make an electron react app, which has 2 windows - a general one and one for the Tray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron, create-react-app

I want to make an Electronjs app with some of the react boilerplates. I guess the best one is
[the one with the most stars in github](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate), but I am open to suggestions.
My goal is to have one window, which is going to be the main one and another one that will be displayed only when the user clicks the Tray(https://github.com/sfatihk/electron-tray-window).
What is the best solution, without using a second html and if possible without ejecting.

Comment: Keep in mind most Linux distros cannot communicate to Electron where the tray icon is located on the screen, so you'll likely have to rely on mouse position on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently researched methods of integrating Election + React & I highly recommend using electron-forge & adding React like this: https://blog.logrocket.com/electron-forge-vs-electron-react-boilerplate/

That article gives you good context from an experienced Slack engineer, but essentially reccommends you follow this in the electron-forge docs: https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript

That is the simplest integration possible & you'll be on solid footing with electron-forge, instead of a GitHub boilerplate.

I however started with a create-react-app project. When combining 2 frameworks, each with large package.json & lots of build tooling I do not like to merge their package.json in a single project. Instead I nested a CRA project inside of electron-forge, & I tell electron to load the /build folder out of CRA. This works for packaging  the app, but during development I use electron-is-dev to load the CRA dev server on port 3001 instead. Use a .env config to change the port the CRA dev server uses to 3001, because both electron-forge & CRA want to use 3000 by default.

To connect actions from your tray window with the main app window, use IPC messages to communicate between those 2 Renderers, with the Main process in between to relay the messages.

Comment: So you are saying that I should tell electron to load different builds for both the tray and the main window?

Comment: @yovchokalev the tray & main window are 2 separate electron 'renderer' processes  running in their own Chromium windows. This means if you are using React they are both 2 different apps. You then use the electron 'main' process to communicate between them as needed. If you take the simple approach in the blog & electron docs, webpack will take care of the building for you. My additional information explains how to use create-react-app & that method would require 2 builds from CRA being copied into your electron app package. I would use the first simple way & skip CRA if you are starting fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution given the existing parameters, would probably be to have a separate route in your application (since you don't want a separate html page), and when the tray icon is clicked, wire it to something like

```
const window = new BrowserWindow();
window.loadUrl('path/to/app/special/route');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Tray](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/tray) in electron for this

Quote from the tray docuentation

> Add icons and context menus to the system's notification area.

Example code:

```
const { app, Menu, Tray } = require('electron')

let tray = null
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  tray = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon')
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Item1', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item2', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true },
    { label: 'Item4', type: 'radio' }
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
})
```

Comment: That is not what I ask. I need to have separate windows, one for the tray(using the package I linked) and one main window. You are showing me how to create a Tray with a menu. The question is more about how to handle routes and webpack configs

Comment: then add more details in your question. I don't know why you are doing it using a separate package when electron already has built in support for this

Comment: There is nothing in the docs about a browser window, which opens, when you click on the tray and always appears depending on the order and OS

Comment: you can write that code yourself. it should be simple